# Drupal behaviors attach to form load

Tags: javascript, modal-dialogs

I am using the simpledialog module with the 'edit' tab still in it. The edit overlay for the node is displayed in the background with the simpledialog still in the way.

I have tried a bunch of ways of attaching the close call to the edit button and triggering a click on the dialog close button. None of it very successfully - all iframes. e.g.

```
$htj2('.tabs.primary').delegate('click', 'a', function() {
    $hjt2('#simple-dialog-container').dialog("close");
```

I think the 'correct drupal pattern' is to attach a behavior to the form load using drupal behaviors.

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.bahaviors.hotTopicsResearch = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            // ?? What next?
            $('#hot-topic-research-node-form',context).once('load', function() {

            });
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

How do I find out what the behaviours are? How do I attach to the load event or is there an event related to clicking on the 'edit' tab? How do I get close the simpledialog?

Comment: it seems like your trying to react to the wrong thing in JS. I assume you're reffering to like this page: http://drupal.org/node/1087026. You want to hide the simpledialog if you press Edit on a node page -- before the Overlay pops up.

You would do that by attaching a simple JS event listener to look for something like `$('a[href~=edit]').clicked() ...` and then simply call simpledialog close or `$('#simplediaglo').hide()`.

my point, I think your attacking it from the wrong direction with the code you've provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it after a number of days searching:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.hotTopicsResearch = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {

            $(document).bind('drupalOverlayBeforeLoad', function(event) {
                $('#simple-dialog-container', context).dialog('close');
            });
        },
        weight: 11
    }

})(jQuery);
```

The other events seem to have the wrong order. 'drupalOverlayOpen' almost works except that the editing overlay never 'becomes active'. This is why I was trying to work on the target editing screen events rather than the open dialog.

overlay_paths without there being'use case documentation' it looks like it only applies to menu items. [How to manually use Drupal 7's admin Overlay?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8220/how-to-manually-use-drupal-7s-admin-overlay/8265#8265) shows you how to add content nodes to the admin paths. This displayed my node in the admin overlay, but without the background context being visible - defeating the point - and with some further quirks.

Comment: I have exactly same problem and I'm not getting it solved :( I've tried the code you posted but the problem stays. Did you made any improvements after posting your code?