# Admin custom module not displaying in theoverlay

Tags: 7

How to show the data fetched from the database in the overlay of the admin custom module.
The data are retrieved but not showing in the overlay. Kindly help me out

Comment: If the question is about code you wrote, please show it. We cannot know what your code is doing, without seeing it; and without seeing it, we can just guess what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Overlay Paths](http://drupal.org/project/overlay_paths)

> This is a simple module that enables site builders to use the built-in
>   Overlay for non-admin pages.

Refer

[Working with the overlay](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/overlay)

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/8265/4471

Comment: This module to view the information submitted by the administrator in backend

Comment: I have made 3 suggestion in my answer. please try the remaining as well.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: myadmin_admin_settings_form in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 763 of D:\wamp\www\lc\candappa\includes\form.inc).
    Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'myadmin_admin_settings_form' not found or invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form() (line 798 of D:\wamp\www\lc\candappa\includes\form.inc).

Comment: This is error i'm facing after using hook_admin_paths.

Comment: That is a PHP error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [hook_admin_paths](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_admin_paths/7) to let Drupal know that your page is an admin page. This will ensure it is displayed in the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You could also give a path on this page in your hook_menu() like

```
admin/config/YOURPAGE
```

and with the appropriate permissions it will show in the admin theme automatically

Comment: <?php 
function myadmin_menu()
{
//this item will show your module name in the admin section
$items['admin/myadmin'] = array
(
'title' => 'Form Submission',
'description' => 'This shows all the form submitted information in the website',
'position' => 'right',
'weight' => -5,
'page callback' => 'system_admin_menu_block_page',
'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
'file' => 'system.admin.inc',
'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'system'),
);

Comment: //this item will be a link under the heading modulename
$items['admin/myadmin/settings'] = array
(
'title' => 'Contact Information',
'description' => 'View the contact details.',
'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
'page arguments' => array('myadmin_admin_settings_form'),
'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
'file' => 'myadmin.admin.inc',
);
return $items;
}

Comment: try $items['admin/config/myadmin/settings']

Comment: <?php
function myadmin_admin_settings_form($form, &$form_state){
  $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {custom_contact} n');
?>
<table cellspacing="0" class="wp-list-table widefat fixed contactss">
  <tr >
    <td><strong>First Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Subject</strong></td>
 <td><strong>Comments</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Option</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <?php  foreach($result as $item) {?>
<tr> <td><?php print $item->first_name;?></td>
    <td><?php print $item->email;?></td></tr>

Comment: this is .inc file. I dont know where i gone wrong